How can I stop harmful content display in blockchain (substrate)?
History cannot be deleted on the blockchain. While images and videos are not stored directly on the blockchain, their IPFS hashes are. IPFS is also censorship-resistant, which is an essential feature. Although content can be censored at the UI level and a reputation system for moderation can be implemented through smart contracts.
Is this an effective method, considering that the content remains accessible in the blockchain's history? How do different blockchain-based social media platforms that already exists prevent harmful content from being displayed?

They're not supposed to prevent harmful content from being displayed. Users who don't want to see it shouldn't view content that may bother them.
